# Spring boot 2.0 takes very long to start with spring-cloud and azure-spring-boot

Tags: azure, spring-boot, spring-cloud, azure-spring-cloud

My spring boot takes around 7-8 minutes to start when it has spring-cloud and azure-spring-boot dependencies on class path. Azure key-vault is used to set environment properties like DB username and password etc. Spring cloud comes along with some custom third party SDK.

The log is full with following:

c.m.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationAuthority : [Correlation ID: 57ca7499-728d-4827-9099-febdbf7b77fa] Instance discovery was successful it never ends.

Comment: Where is this running e.g. azure functions?

Comment: Inside docker container. I get this error on local machine as well

Comment: Can you add your POM details that you have included for DB dependencies to your question.

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems similar to the one reported here:
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot/issues/637

If confirmed to be the same issue, it should have already been fix in https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot/pull/882

If the slowness issue still persists, please raise [Azure Support Ticket](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/) to get help.